# Nextjs - if i dont use getServerSideProps or getStaticProps are my static pages then served optimised?

Tags: next.js, static, server-side-rendering

Speaking about Next.js v12
Should i render completely static pages like contact page or policy pages with empty getStaticProps exports or without anything to serve them with results created during build time?

Comment: Time has gone. Please select an answer or answer your question and select as resolved. This helps keep Stack Overflow tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the page component in plain JSX/React. Empty exports are not needed. The framework will “optimize” everything for you. Use Next.js components, like the `<Link>` component, to get additional advantages (preloading). Your site will be very fast! Keep reading the docs! Next.js is not trivial!

Answer (score 0):

If your page content is entirely static and doesn't require any data fetching or pre-processing, you can omit the `getStaticProps` function altogether. Next.js will automatically treat the page as static during the build process. when you build your page, your dynamic pages will be marked with `lambda` sign and static pages as `round` sign

`getStaticProps` is used for pre-rendering pages with Static Generation (SSG). It allows you to fetch data at build time and pass it as props to your page components. for example if you have 10 blog posts in your database, during build time it will fetch all the blog ids and generate html for each blog and cache it.